# Ansible shell module execute kubectl error connection to localhost refused

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubectl

I have an ansible script that I am using to build a kubernetes cluster. If I run `kubectl` via the shell module:

```
- name: Ensure kube-apiserver-to-kubelet ClusterRole is applied
  shell: "kubectl apply -f kube-apiserver-to-kubelet.yaml"
  delegate_to: controller1
  run_once: true
```

I get the following error "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?":

```
fatal: [controller1 -> 10.240.0.11]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "kubectl apply -f kube-apiserver-to-kubelet.yaml", "delta": "0:00:00.116446", "end": "2018-04-15 21:42:51.023786", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2018-04-15 21:42:50.907340", "stderr": "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?", "stderr_lines": ["The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

However, if I log into `controller1` (I use a bastion host as a proxy to the nodes.) and execute the command it runs without issue:

```
kubectl apply -f kube-apiserver-to-kubelet.yaml
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "system:kube-apiserver-to-kubelet" configured
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "system:kube-apiserver" configured
```

Why does this work on the node directly but not via ansible and what do I need to be doing to make this run without failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely not picking up your kubeconfig (localhost:8080 is the unconfigured default)

I would either use the builtin "k8s_raw" module or specify the --kubeconfig parameter in your shell script

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'd tried it with the `--kubeconfig` flag too. I've not actually configured the controller to use a kubeconfig though. Perhaps some more investigating required on my part.

Comment: You do need some way of authenticating to Kubernetes, and kubeconfig is the "default" way. That said, without knowing more about your env its hard to provide guidance.

Comment: This one works for me when add ```--kubeconfig=/home/ubuntu/.kube/config```.  Full version of command: ```shell: kubectl --kubeconfig=/home/dialog/.kube/config -n kube-system get configmap/kube-proxy -o yaml```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot.  This flag  also run for me

```
- name: 'Run secret'
  register: secret
  command: "kubectl apply -f . --kubeconfig=/home/ubuntu/.kube/config"
  args:
     chdir: "/home/ubuntu/secret/"

- debug:
    var: secret.stdout_lines
```

Comment: For no apparently reason, all of my playbooks started failing for anything dealing with `kubectl`.  The config is working on the Ansible user if you ssh in directly.  But using, shell, command, or the k8s module all resulted in not being able to find or access the `kubeconfig` variable.  This is the only thing I could get to work (the `--kubeconfig` flag in line).  I suspect it is something that has happened with my Ansible install.